# React Native android build

Tags: android, windows, react-native, android-studio-2.2

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
I was following this tutorial to get an Android app running on Windows. When running the `react-native run-android` command, I get this error:

:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT out(2119206397) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1004599865) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(126533033) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(520573141) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(2000135048) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1888282095) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(100816428) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(323189884) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1803421983) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(323189884) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(100816428) : No Delegate set : lost message:Crunching C:\Windows\System32\myapp\android\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.1\res\drawable-xxxhdpi\abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015.png
AAPT out(1004599865) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done

:app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Miguel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Sorry for the name I've been working on this for a whole entire day

Comment: Sorry I've been filling out this post for hours because I don't want to post something without ensuring that I haven't tried everything that I can think of so the last letters of build got removed somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making sure that all of my packages were updated the error went away. I installed all of the build tools, sdk packages and platform tools that were available in the android-studio sdk manager. Make sure that everything is updated and this error should go away. Also make sure that you have a local.properties file in the project/android directory with a path to the sdk.

put this in your local.properties file.

`sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Miguel\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk2`

This is a great tutorial for this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnqyUnASuk8

Update: Make sure to install the IntelX86 system image if you want adb to connect to the emulator when building your project.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem , and after spending so much time and lots of searching about this issue the only trick worked for :

1. Please Install the Required SDKs as shown in this figure [Configure Required SDKs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoKdm.png)
2. If You have already installed it, so you must have to update the following SDKs:

   - `Android SDK Tool` (update it to latest version)
   - `Android SDK Platform-tools` (update it to latest version)
   - `Android SDK Build-tools` (update it to latest version)
   - `Android Support Repository` under `Extra` folder (update it to latest version)
3. You Must have at least Installed the Same version `Android API` as the installed `Android SDK Build-tools` & `Android SDK Platform-tools` version as shown in the figure [Configure Required SDKs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoKdm.png)
4. Must sure that the path of the SDK is shown correctly in the PATH environment variable and ANDROID_HOME environment variable ...

> **Note:** Local Maven repository for Support Libraries which is listed as the SDK requirement in the official docs of React-native is now named as Android Support Repository in the SDK Manager .

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this problem the hardway. This error will also occur if your project name contains special characters like `-`

app.json

`{
  "name": "some-database",
  "displayName": "somw-database"
}`

It will fail with the same error!